# Command Prompt in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to add a command prompt that opens in project folder when I right click my project to open a context menu -- see below:
[image]

I know how to create a command prompt link through `Tools > External Tools` but I don't know how to add that link to my context menu.

Could someone tell me how I can do this? Thanks.

P.S. I'm currently using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 i.e. 15.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Open Command Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) extension to open a command prompt on the project's path.